# Who is running my PowerShell script in IIS?

Tags: c#, powershell, iis, exchange-server

I am perplexed by something.  So I created a ASP.NET C# Web Application with Visual Studio 2022.  The application uses Windows authentication when someone comes to the site.  When I created the new website in IIS on Windows 10 and then published the application the PowerShell script seems to work for everyone.  I am surprised because the output is something that calls Exchange Server and returns if ActiveSync is enabled.  Only a few of us can do this thought maybe everyone can do it for their own account.  That said, I do not believe there is any impersonation going on so curious how it's working.

In IIS have:

- Authentication: Windows Authentication Enabled
- All other Authentication Disabled
- App Pool uses Integrated Managed Pipeline and ApplicationPoolIdentity for the Identity.  Not sure what that identity is.

Call being run is basically:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
PSSnapInException ex;
ps.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out ex);
string script = string.Format("(Get-CASMailbox -Identity {0} ).ActiveSyncEnabled", GetCurrentUserWindowsLogin());
ps.AddScript(script);
Collection<PSObject> output = ps.Invoke();
```

So it basically fills in {0} with the domain\username of the user and returns True or False if ActiveSync is enabled.  Before I was given special access to see other people's status, I couldn't even see their accounts and PowerShell would error out.  So the average personal can't see other people's status.

Also WWW Publishing Service is running as LocalSystem account.

Any thoughts how this is working right now?  Note the computer itself is logged in as me and I can run this from any other computer's browser so wouldn't think the logged in user would matter but not sure.

Comment: "WWW Publishing Service is running as LocalSystem account." - that usually means it'll attempt to authenticate as the computer's active directory account, so `domain\computer$`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Going to be sad if the computer account has permissions on Exchange that my personal domain account doesn't.  Sounds like a hole.  But if that's the case, does changing the identity on the app pool to say my personal domain\uesrname override that?  Guess would be impersonation?  Also reached out to the Exchange person to see if they could see who is making the request.  Probably going to spawn a whole thing.

Comment: What is the output of `[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name` or `whoami` from within the script? Maybe like `whoami | out-file ./identity.txt` to try and see it. I think App Pools usually show up as Network Service (the domain computer account). Any MailRecipient can run `Get-CASMailbox` if they can connect to the exchange shell, but I'd be surprised if your computer object had a mailbox.

Comment: Gooi ideas.  I did the following

Response.Write("Get Current: " + System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

Got: 

Get Current: IIS APPPOOL\activesync

Tried doing the above but don't think it liked out-file.  Tried doing like this but nothing was written so may have failed:

            string iCmdText = "whoami > c:\\temp\\identity.txt";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", CmdText);

Comment: Also got output of whoami.  Was the same iis apppool\activesync

Comment: It seems that application pool use the identity of domain account to run powershell.

Comment: So the thought is it's somehow using the identity of the user logged into the website to authenticate?  Do we think we know this or an educated guess?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, applications are run as the identity of application pool, unless impersonation is used, it will run as the user logged in.